# I'm getting this error when ever I'm executing my stored procedure " PLS-00103"

Tags: oracle, syntax, plsql, syntax-error, pls-00103

I'm trying to execute stored procedure, I'm getting stuck in 54 line 'EXECUTE IMMEDIATE' basically. I'm passing SQL statement into for loop.Please let me know I'm doing wrong somewhere?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure DE_DUP_PROC (Dy_File_Name  in USER_TABLES.table_name%type,
                                         SUPPLIER_CD   in varchar2,
                                         EXT_PHARMA_ID in varchar2,
                                         FLAG_VALUE    in varchar2,
                                         DE_REC_COUNT  out NUMBER)   --RETURN NUMBER
AS
  SEQ_NO_SHO Number(38);                          --EEEE
  WYYYYNNN VARCHAR2(250) := 'W2015021';
  YYYYNNN VARCHAR2(10);
  CUR_DATE Date;
  --De_Rec_Count Number(38) := 3456;
  DE_DUB_OUTPUT_FILE VARCHAR2(100);

  /*CURSOR De_DUB_CUR IS */
  DE_DUB_SQL_STATMNT VARCHAR2(3000) := 'SELECT S.TRANS_GUID AS OLD_TRANS_GUID,
  H.TRANS_GUID    AS NEW_TRANS_GUID,
  CASE
      WHEN H.TRANS_GUID IS NULL
      THEN 0
      ELSE 1
  END as TRN_STAT,P.INTR_PHARMACY_ID as INT_PHARMACY_ID ,S.EXTRNL_PHARMACY_ID as EXT_PHARMACY_ID ,S.PHARMACY_NM as PHARMACY_NAME ,S.PHARMACY_ADDR as PHARMACY_ADDRESS,
      S.SUPPLIERS_PSCR_DRUG_CD as SP_PSCR_DRUG_CD,  S.PSCR_DRUG_IPU_CD as PS_DRUG_IPU_CD,''IPU'' as IPU_Value,  S.PSCR_DRUG_DESC as PS_DRUG_DESC,
      S.DSPNSD_DRUG_PACK_SIZE as DS_DRUG_PACK_SIZE, S.RX_ID as R_ID,  S.RX_ITEM_SEQ as R_ITEM_SEQ,  S.RX_REPEAT_STATUS as R_REPEAT_STATUS,  S.RX_TYP as R_TYPE,
      S.EXMT_STATUS as EX_STATUS,S.PSCR_QTY as PS_QTY,  S.NRSG_HM_IND as NR_HM_IND,S.RX_DSPNSD_DT as R_DSPNSD_DT,  S.RX_DSPNSD_TM as R_DSPNSD_TM,
      S.SUPPLIERS_DSPNSD_DRUG_CD as SP_DSPNSD_DRUG_CD,  S.DSPNSD_DRUG_IPU_CD as DS_DRUG_IPU_CD, ''IPU'' as IPU_Value2,S.DSPNSD_DRUG_DESC as DS_DRUG_DESC,
      S.GENERIC_USE_MARKER as GC_USE_MARKER,  S.DSPNSD_UNIT_OF_QTY as DS_UNIT_OF_QTY,  S.DSPNSD_QTY as DS_QTY, ''EUR'' as EUR_Value1,S.COST_OF_DSPNSD_QTY as CT_OF_DSPNSD_QTY ,
      S.VERBOSE_DOSAGE as VER_DOSAGE FROM
      (SELECT stg.*,  row_number() over (partition BY key_clmns_hash ORDER BY 1) AS RN FROM '|| Dy_File_Name ||' stg ) s
      LEFT JOIN ps_pharmacy p
      ON s.extrnl_pharmacy_id = p.extrnl_pharmacy_id
      LEFT JOIN ps_rx_hist H
      ON h.key_clmns_hash        = s.key_clmnS_hash
      AND h.rx_dspnsd_dt         = s.rx_dspnsd_dt
      AND s.supplier_pharmacy_cd = h.SUPPLIER_PHARMACY_CD
      AND s.detl_clmns_hash <> h.detl_clmns_hash
      WHERE s.RN                 = 1';
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT count(*) into DE_REC_COUNT
                       FROM  (SELECT stg.*, row_number() over ( partition BY key_clmns_hash ORDER BY 1 ) AS RN FROM '|| Dy_File_Name ||' stg ) s
                       LEFT JOIN ps_pharmacy p ON s.extrnl_pharmacy_id = p.extrnl_pharmacy_id LEFT JOIN ps_rx_hist H ON h.key_clmns_hash = s.key_clmnS_hash
                        AND h.rx_dspnsd_dt = s.rx_dspnsd_dt AND s.supplier_pharmacy_cd = h.SUPPLIER_PHARMACY_CD AND s.detl_clmns_hash <> h.detl_clmns_hash WHERE S.RN = 1';

  IF DE_REC_COUNT > 0 THEN

    --select sysdate into CUR_DATE from dual;
    --select  PROC_PD_CD into WYYYYNNN from PS_ADMIN.PS_PROC_PD where PD_STRT_DT <= CURRENT_DATE and PD_END_DT >= CURRENT_DATE;
    --select  PROC_PD_CD into WYYYYNNN from PS_ADMIN.PS_PROC_PD where PD_STRT_DT <= CURRENT_DATE and PD_END_DT >= CURRENT_DATE; -- PD_STRT_DT<='16-AUG-15' and PD_STRT_DT >= '16-AUG-15';
    select replace(WYYYYNNN,'W','') into YYYYNNN from dual;
    SELECT PS_GET_PROC_PD(SUPPLIER_CD,EXT_PHARMA_ID,YYYYNNN) into SEQ_NO_SHO FROM DUAL;
    select 'LRXIE'||FLAG_VALUE||'10_'||SUPPLIER_CD||'_'||EXT_PHARMA_ID||'_'||WYYYYNNN||'_'||SEQ_NO_SHO||'_'||DE_REC_COUNT||'.TXT' into DE_DUB_OUTPUT_FILE from dual;

    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( De_Dub_Output_File );

    FOR De_Dub_rec IN  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE DE_DUB_SQL_STATMNT
    LOOP
      dbms_output.enable(100000);

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('"' || De_Dub_rec.OLD_TRANS_GUID || '"|"' || De_Dub_rec.NEW_TRANS_GUID || '"|' || De_Dub_rec.TRN_STAT || '|' ||  De_Dub_rec.INT_PHARMACY_ID || '|' || De_Dub_rec.EXT_PHARMACY_ID || '|"' ||
      De_Dub_rec.PHARMACY_NAME|| '"|"' || De_Dub_rec.PHARMACY_ADDRESS || '"|' || De_Dub_rec.SP_PSCR_DRUG_CD || '|' || De_Dub_rec.PS_DRUG_IPU_CD || '|"' || De_Dub_rec.IPU_Value || '"|"' ||
      De_Dub_rec.PS_DRUG_DESC || '"|' || De_Dub_rec.DS_DRUG_PACK_SIZE || '|"' || De_Dub_rec.R_ID || '"|' || De_Dub_rec.R_ITEM_SEQ || '|' || De_Dub_rec.R_REPEAT_STATUS || '|"' ||
      De_Dub_rec.R_TYPE || '"|"' || De_Dub_rec.EX_STATUS || '"|' || De_Dub_rec.PS_QTY || '|' || De_Dub_rec.NR_HM_IND || '|"' || De_Dub_rec.R_DSPNSD_DT || '"|' || De_Dub_rec.R_DSPNSD_TM || '|' ||
      De_Dub_rec.SP_DSPNSD_DRUG_CD || '|' || De_Dub_rec.DS_DRUG_IPU_CD|| '|"' || De_Dub_rec.IPU_Value2 || '"|"' || De_Dub_rec.DS_DRUG_DESC|| '"|' || De_Dub_rec.GC_USE_MARKER|| '|"' ||
      De_Dub_rec.DS_UNIT_OF_QTY|| '"|' || De_Dub_rec.DS_QTY|| '|"' || De_Dub_rec.EUR_Value1|| '"|' || De_Dub_rec.CT_OF_DSPNSD_QTY || '|"' || De_Dub_rec.VER_DOSAGE || '"');
    END LOOP;

    DE_REC_COUNT :=0;
  ELSE
    DE_REC_COUNT :=1;
  END IF;

END DE_DUP_PROC;
/
```

I'm getting this error:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
58/44    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IMMEDIATE" when expecting one
         of the following:
         . ( * @ % & - + / at loop mod remainder rem ..
         <an exponent (**)> || multiset
         The symbol ". was inserted before "IMMEDIATE" to continue.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors in your code. The first one is the compiler error you get. You can't use an `execute immediate` in a `for` loop (which is [clearly documented in the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/controlstatements.htm#CJAIJFCI))

You need to open a cursor and then loop over the cursor. So instead of

```
FOR De_Dub_rec IN  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE DE_DUB_SQL_STATMNT
```

you need to use something like this:

```
OPEN De_Dub_cursor FOR DE_DUB_SQL_STATMNT;
LOOP  
  FETCH De_Dub_cursor INTO de_dub_cursor_record;
  EXIT WHEN cv%NOTFOUND;   

  ... do your stuff here

END LOOP;
```

**Of course you will need to declare the cursor `De_Dub_cursor` and the record variable `de_dub_cursor_record`**. Note that the record variables needs to be defined with all columns that your result returns (which essentially requires a new `TYPE` to be defined if I'm not mistaken)

The second error you have won't show up until you run the code. You have an `INTO variable` clause *inside* your SQL string for the first `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. This will not work. The into clause can not be used like that. You need to remove the `into DE_REC_COUNT` part from the string literal and use the `INTO` clause as an option to the `execute immediate` statement. Something like this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT count(*) FROM ....'
   INTO DE_REC_COUNT;
```

---

Unrelated to your problems, but the `select ... from dual` can be replaced with a simple assignment.

So instead of

```
select replace(WYYYYNNN,'W','') into YYYYNNN from dual;
```

use

```
YYYYNNN := replace(WYYYYNNN,'W','');
```

or instead of:

```
SELECT PS_GET_PROC_PD(SUPPLIER_CD,EXT_PHARMA_ID,YYYYNNN) into SEQ_NO_SHO FROM DUAL;
select 'LRXIE'||FLAG_VALUE||'10_'||SUPPLIER_CD||'_'||EXT_PHARMA_ID||'_'||WYYYYNNN||'_'||SEQ_NO_SHO||'_'||DE_REC_COUNT||'.TXT' into DE_DUB_OUTPUT_FILE from dual;
```

use

```
SEQ_NO_SHO := PS_GET_PROC_PD(SUPPLIER_CD,EXT_PHARMA_ID,YYYYNNN);
DE_DUB_OUTPUT_FILE := 'LRXIE'||FLAG_VALUE||'10_'||SUPPLIER_CD||'_'||EXT_PHARMA_ID||'_'||WYYYYNNN||'_'||SEQ_NO_SHO||'_'||DE_REC_COUNT||'.TXT';
```

Comment: more detailed answer than mine and better solution with the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

First, should be `execute immediate 'select count(*) from ...' into DE_REC_COUNT;`

That's what I see at first scan, but the fail is at second execute immediate.

There you should create a collection and execute immediate the query and bulk collect into that collection.
Then, you should loop in that collection and do the work that you do(the dbms_output stuff).